# Refund / Credits - PHP REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'm currently testing the new Paypal REST API in PHP and it would appear that I have everything working just fine. However the company I am adding this support for is looking to drop their current Payment Gateway in favor of Paypal. This is where the problem exists.

Currently all charges have occurred only on this other Payment Gateway. When they drop that Payment Gateway in favor of Paypal they will no doubtedly have customers who want to cancel services and based on company policy will receive a pro-rated refund.

So here is my question. Is it even possible to issue a refund using the Paypal REST API? Keep in mind, all charges are currently done without Paypal, so the Transaction ID's will not be found in Paypal. So I cannot associate an ID to Paypal to reference.

Currently they only accept Credit Cards. I'm lost at this point on a proper solution based on my question. The current Payment Gateway has a "Credit" option where it does not require a Transaction ID to be associated.

Any guidance would be helpful.